# Erlang: Using Bit Syntax to add a String in little endian format

Tags: erlang

What's the proper way to add a String of arbitrary size to a Binary using the Bit Syntax? Everything needs to be in little endian. I've tried this:

```
example() ->
  Cmd = 16#4e584e43,
  Text = "hello::",
  <<Cmd:32/unsigned-little-integer,Text/little-bitstring>>.
```

But get the exception:

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  bit_size/1
    called as bit_size("hello::")
 in call from packet:example/0
 in call from packet:main/0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
<<Cmd:32/unsigned-little-integer,(list_to_binary(Text))/binary>>.
```

This just treats your string as a binary with one byte per character, so no endianness applies.

Comment: Yes that works. I actually got it to work by using this as well:  Header = <<Cmd:32/unsigned-little-integer>>, list_to_binary([Header,Text]).   Thanks!